# Яндекс.Поделиться и код WP

Tags: javascript, wordpress, share, ya-share2

Друзья, помогите решить проблему. Хочу чтобы при нажатии кнопок Яндекс.Поделиться скрипт брал не логотип сайта, а изображение, привязанное к данному посту в Wordpress. Подскажите как правильно прописать в атрибуте data-image ссылку на изображение поста с помощью вордпрессовского get_the_post_thumbnail_url ?

Answer (score 1):

```
... data-image="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>" ...
```

Или

```
global $post;
... data-image="<?php get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post ) ?>" ...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Проблема решилась, но не полностью. ВК и Pinterest теперь подхватывают нужную картинку поста, а вот все остальные сети и мессенджеры продолжают вставлять логотип сайта.

Comment: @g0rka если проблема решилась - отметь ответ решеннием. А вообще почитай про микроразметку и Open Graph в частности.